# if blank value in entire column then remove from output

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

i am not sure whether it is possible but appreciate if any one can help me on this.

**if the column is blank for all the output rows then should not appear in the output.**

sample data:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(

BaseVehicle VARCHAR (50),   
SubModel    VARCHAR (50),
Make    VARCHAR (50),
Years   VARCHAR (50),
FromYear VARCHAR (50),  
ToYear  VARCHAR (50)
)


INSERT @T

SELECT '1979 Ford LTD','','FORD','1979','','' UNION ALL     
SELECT '1979 Ford LTD','','FORD','1979','','2005' UNION ALL         
SELECT '1979 Ford LTD','','FORD','1979','','' UNION ALL         
SELECT '1979 Ford LTD','','FORD','1979','',''
```

Expected Output

```
BaseVehicle   |Make|year|toyear
1979 Ford LTD |ford|1979|
1979 Ford LTD |ford|1979|2005
1979 Ford LTD |ford|1979|
1979 Ford LTD |ford|1979|
```

Thanks

Comment: it is not appearing your query is working

Comment: I would suggest to hide the columns on the code behind instead.

Comment: are you saying my sample data is not working?

Comment: You can not conditionally exclude columns in the result...

Comment: is there no way at all... :(

Comment: i think you maybe looking to do something with COALESCE?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Comment: @Shan You can, but there is way too much work and the performance loss might be big. I also think you can do this much easier in the application code.

Comment: please suggest. Client is not worrying about performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the count of cells which is null with the count of all. If both matches, then the entire column in null. Then leave that column from the selection.

**Query**

```
create table #T
(
   BaseVehicle VARCHAR (50),   
   SubModel    VARCHAR (50),
   Make    VARCHAR (50),
   Years   VARCHAR (50),
   FromYear VARCHAR (50),  
   ToYear  VARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT into #T 
SELECT '1979 Ford LTD','','FORD','1979','','' UNION ALL     
SELECT '1979 Ford LTD','','FORD','1979','','2005' UNION ALL         
SELECT '1979 Ford LTD','','FORD','1979','','' UNION ALL         
SELECT '1979 Ford LTD','','FORD','1979','',''

declare @strsql varchar(2500)
  set @strsql = 'select '
  set @strsql += 
  (select case when  (select COUNT(*) from #T where BaseVehicle = '') 
  <> (select count(*) from #T ) then 'BaseVehicle, ' else '' end)
  set @strsql += 
  (select case when  (select COUNT(*) from #T  where SubModel = '') 
  <> (select count(*) from #T ) then 'SubModel, ' else '' end)
  set @strsql += 
  (select case when  (select COUNT(*) from #T  where Make = '') 
  <> (select count(*) from #T ) then 'Make, ' else '' end)
  set @strsql += 
  (select case when  (select COUNT(*) from #T  where Years = '') 
  <> (select count(*) from #T ) then 'Years, ' else '' end)
  set @strsql += 
  (select case when  (select COUNT(*) from #T  where FromYear = '') 
  <> (select count(*) from #T ) then 'FromYear, ' else '' end)
  set @strsql += 
  (select case when  (select COUNT(*) from #T  where ToYear = '') 
  <> (select count(*) from #T ) then 'ToYear, ' else '' end)
  set @strsql = LEFT(@strsql,len(@strsql) -1)
  set @strsql += ' from #T'

  exec (@strsql)
```

**Result**

```
BaseVehicle     Make    Years   ToYear
1979 Ford LTD   FORD    1979    
1979 Ford LTD   FORD    1979    2005
1979 Ford LTD   FORD    1979    
1979 Ford LTD   FORD    1979
```

Even you can make the query dynamically if the table is there in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

Comment: @Shan, here is an improved version of Ulas's answer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/4266/0

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do this with temp table, because you can alter it. But I wouldn't recommend to do this:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(
BaseVehicle VARCHAR (50),   
SubModel    VARCHAR (50),
Make    VARCHAR (50),
Years   VARCHAR (50),
FromYear VARCHAR (50),  
ToYear  VARCHAR (50))

INSERT @T
SELECT '1979 Ford LTD','','FORD','1979','','' UNION ALL     
SELECT '1979 Ford LTD','','FORD','1979','','2005' UNION ALL         
SELECT '1979 Ford LTD','','FORD','1979','','' UNION ALL         
SELECT '1979 Ford LTD','','FORD','1979','','' 

SELECT * INTO #staging FROM @T

IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #staging WHERE BaseVehicle <> ''))
    ALTER TABLE #staging DROP COLUMN BaseVehicle

IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #staging WHERE SubModel <> ''))
    ALTER TABLE #staging DROP COLUMN SubModel

IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #staging WHERE Make <> ''))
    ALTER TABLE #staging DROP COLUMN Make

IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #staging WHERE Years <> ''))
    ALTER TABLE #staging DROP COLUMN Years

IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #staging WHERE FromYear <> ''))
    ALTER TABLE #staging DROP COLUMN FromYear

IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #staging WHERE ToYear <> ''))
    ALTER TABLE #staging DROP COLUMN ToYear

SELECT * FROM #staging
DROP TABLE #staging
```

Output:

```
BaseVehicle     Make    Years   ToYear
1979 Ford LTD   FORD    1979    
1979 Ford LTD   FORD    1979    2005
1979 Ford LTD   FORD    1979    
1979 Ford LTD   FORD    1979
```

Answer (score 1):

The number of columns in any given SQL query is static. There is no syntax to dynamically add or remove columns from a SQL query.

You could hack together something that does two queries: first to determine if one or more rows has a value, then the second time doing one of two different SELECTs, one containing the extra column in the list and one not.

Something like:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @T WHERE Submodel <> '')
    SELECT BaseVehicle, Submodel, Make, Year, FromYears, ToYear FROM @T
ELSE
    SELECT BaseVehicle, Make, Year, FromYears, ToYear FROM @T;
```

As you may guess, this is getting pretty hacky and not a general solution. So if you need this for multiple columns and/or tables it would get pretty unmanageable.

This actually sounds like something better suited at the application layer. Whatever code is running the query and processing the result is better suited to showing and hiding columns.